# How can I send ALT + F4 to the active browser window in protractor?

Tags: protractor

How can I send `ALT+F4` to the active browser window. I don't want to use `browser.close()` as that is not working as expected for me.

Comment: Please try this: browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.ALT).sendKeys(protractor.Key.F4).perform();

Comment: Gives me a Syntax error- Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: I tried splitting it.`browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.ALT).perform();` goes through fine. I think `sendKeys(protractor.Key.F4).perfor‌​m()` is causing the issue. Does `sendKeys()` support Function keys?

Comment: `browser.close() as that is not working as expected for me` what do you mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry! I should have elaborated that in the question only. `browser.close` is not working as expected for the web application where closing a pop up window has some desired behavior.

Comment: Which browsers have you tried it on? And which versions of the drivers? Make sure you are running with the latest. A recent version of the chrome-driver would occasionally drop keys during the sendKeys() function. Updating to the latest solved the problem.

Comment: Yes Andrew, I  am checking on the latest version. The problem is not with the browser, `sendKeys(protractor.Key.F4).perfor‌​m()` itself gives me an error which means that probably the windows function keys are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I find this works through Chromedriver for Chromium:

```
return browser.actions().mouseMove( $('body') )
    .click()
    .keyDown( protractor.Key.ALT )
    .sendKeys( protractor.Key.F4 )
    .perform();
```